# How to access SharePoint Lists in Frame work web-part?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

Am on creating a simple SharePoint to-do list web-part, to do this need to access the SharePoint List named **To-doList** there i stored all the tasks. how could i access it through the type script or is there any methods in SharePoint Frame Works ?

```
    private _getlistdata(): void{
  let html: string="";
  const elemennt: Element= this.domElement.querySelector("#listdata");

  pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("DispListApp").get().then(Response => {



      elemennt.innerHTML= html;
});
}
```

i have added this code and get connect to the List Named **DispListApp** but unable to display the list items Can u Pls Help Me @saad

Comment: Your driving instructor did not steer you onto that busy highway within 10 minutes of your first lesson. Learning SPFx is equally difficult, so start with all those examples (granted, they are not always top notch examples): https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on framework you are using like jquery, angular etc. i will recommend using PNP for crud operations with knockout.

```
import { Web } from "sp-pnp-js";
```

and in constructor add

```
this.pnpWeb = new Web("https://saad345.sharepoint.com/sites/dcdeveloper");
```

and finally

```
readListItems = function () {
    this.status("Loading ....");

    this.pnpWeb.lists.getById("Your list GUID")
      .items.select('Title', 'Id').get()
      .then((items: IListItem[]): void => {
        this.status("Error Loading items ....");
        if (items != undefined && items != null) {
          this._selectedListItems(items);
          this.status("Successfully loaded all list items");
        }
      }, (error: any): void => {
        this.status('Loading all items failed with error: ' + error);
      });
     }
```

You can use getByTitle method as an alternative to getById as well, i can help you further in case you need help.